# Universal Application in IOS9 with autolayout

Tags: ios9, ios-universal-app

How can it be achieve to make the single `storyboard` file to work in `iphone` and as well as in ipad in `iOS9` using apdaptive layout.As Application in `iphone` used singleviewcontroller but in `iPad` it is used master detail application.

Answer (score 0):

**This is for xCode 7.0+**

While in `Main.storyboard`, at the bottom of the screen you'll see `w Any h Any`

If you click on that, a view will popup with your size values. From there you can select a different size class.

Once you select a different size class, you can edit your layouts for that size class specifically.

For iPads you would select all of the rectangles.

Comment: Thanks for your reply that i know but my question is that how to manage masterviewcontroller for ipad and singleviewcontroller for iphone.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to have single storyboard file for both iPhone and iPad without autolayout!!! If you are not planning to use auto layout , at least you should use two storyboard files for iPhone and iPad!!!

Comment: The title indicates that OP wants to use autolayout.